# data structure fails to instantiate GMS2

Tags: game-maker

Error message:
Data structure with index does not exist.
 at gml_Object_enemy_actor_Step_0 (line 10) -           hand[i] = ds_stack_push(deck);

Code snippit that is referenced in the error message:

```
if global.phase == 0
{
    //fill inital hand of cards
    if global.turn == 0 && hand[0] = noone
    {
        for (i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            hand[i] = ds_stack_push(deck);
        }
    }
}
```

The code that creates the ds_stack

```
/// @description hold the enemy player's outfit

scale = 0.25;

image_xscale = scale;
image_yscale = scale;

outfit = ds_stack_create();
hand = array_create(8,noone);
//hand[0] = noone;
draw = false;

//create a deck and fill it
deck = ds_stack_create();
fill_deck(deck);
```

The fill_deck() function just adds usable numbers to the ds_stack

```
//argument0 is the deck being passed to fill

var temp = ds_stack_create();

for (i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    var index = round(irandom(46));
    ds_stack_push(temp, index);
}

ds_stack_copy(argument0,temp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> hand[i] = ds_stack_push(deck);

maybe you wanted `hand[i] = ds_stack_pop(deck);`?

And couple things...

```
//argument0 is the deck being passed to fill

var temp = ds_stack_create();

for (i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    var index = round(irandom(46));
    ds_stack_push(temp, index);
}

ds_stack_copy(argument0,temp);
```

don't forget to destroy `temp` data structure, otherwise you'll have a memory leak. And you can fill it without extra data structure:

```
var data = argument0;

for (var i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    var index = irandom(46);
    ds_stack_push(data, index);
}
```

And you don't need use `round()`, because `irandom` already is integer.